# Mousemove and onclick events

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, mousemove

I am making a slider and I detect the position of the mouse to define click event. I create a `$(document).on('mousemove')` event and when I am on the position I want a click, I add a `on('click')` event, but in this case, the event it's called so many time, and not just one time.

Let's see this code. Here is a quick example : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JeremDsgn/9WN9r/1/)

```
var widthScreen = $(window).width();

$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    console.log(e.pageX);

    if (e.pageX > (widthScreen - 120) && e.pageX < widthScreen) {
        $('ul').addClass('right-show');

        $('li').eq(2).on('click', function() {
            console.log('too much click');
        });
    } else {
        $('ul').removeClass('right-show');
    }
});
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: What else to expect, when you attach your click listener in another event handler, even in a one, which fires several times per second.

Comment: yes, as Teemu said, you are binding click listener `$('li').eq(2).on('click', function() {
            console.log('too much click');
        });` inside `mousemove` event, so its getting binded multiple times.

Comment: This is calling the mousemove event for every mouse move. So the event is executed many times. Attach the mousemove event to the ul element.

Comment: Yes I know, but there is any wait to avoid this behavior ? @Vinoth I tried to remplace `document`with `ul`it's the same problem.

Comment: I added the answer. Please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When ever you do the mousemove, it is checking the condition and attaching the click event. So the click event is attached many times. To avoid this, first remove the click event using `off('click')` and attach it. Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9WN9r/2/).

```
var widthScreen = $(window).width();

$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    console.log(e.pageX);

    if (e.pageX > (widthScreen - 120) && e.pageX < widthScreen) {
        $('ul').addClass('right-show');

        $('li').eq(2).off('click').on('click', function() {
            console.log('too much click');
        });
    } else {
        $('ul').removeClass('right-show');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the event attachment from mousemove handler, and create a flag to check, if the cursor is on correct position:

```
var widthScreen = $(window).width(),
    onArea = false;

$(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
    if (e.pageX > (widthScreen - 120) && e.pageX < widthScreen) {
        $('ul').addClass('right-show');
        onArea = true;
    } else {
        $('ul').removeClass('right-show');
        onArea = false;
    }
});

$('li').eq(2).on('click', function(e) {
    if (onArea) {
        console.log('Not too much clicks.');
    }
});
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5xU4/).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at underscore.js throttle function:

```
_.throttle(function, wait, [options])
```

Creates and returns a new, throttled version of the passed function, that, when invoked repeatedly, will only actually call the original function at most once per every wait milliseconds. Useful for rate-limiting events that occur faster than you can keep up with

Comment: I don't want to use underscore. I just want to find a workaround to solve this problem with js/jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Use .one() instead of .on() [Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fone%2F&ei=HmzLU4isL8iw0AX98oCgBQ&usg=AFQjCNFfRrylQSDCa7edgzaUeRrJLanfvQ&sig2=6-ci-ZwKgRRp0mF2QsOfKQ)